# Why feed forward neural network (FFN) in transformer block has a "contract and expand" pattern?

Tags: transformer, pytorch

I noticed that in many (every ?) transformer architecture, the FFN (i.e the MLP network at the end of one transformer block) consists of two linear layers (with an activation) where the first layer goes from D1 channels to D2 channels and the second layer goes back from D2 to D1.

For instance we can see it in this FFN class in DistilBert :
https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/345b9b1a6a308a1fa6559251eb33ead2211240ac/src/transformers/models/distilbert/modeling_distilbert.py#L455

What justifies this "expand and contract" pattern ? Why not just using two identical linear layers or anything else ?